# upload data to S3 with sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a problem with SageMaker when I try to upload Data into S3 bucket . I get this error :

> ---
>
> ```
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-26-d21b1cb0fcab> in <module>()
>      19 download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-train.rec')
>      20 
> ---> 21 upload_to_s3('train', 'caltech-256-60-train.rec')
>
> <ipython-input-26-d21b1cb0fcab> in upload_to_s3(channel, file)
>      13     data = open(file, "rb")
>      14     key = channel + '/' + file
> ---> 15     s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=key, Body=data)
>      16 
>      17 
>
> NameError: name 'bucket' is not defined
> ```

Here is the script:

```python
import os
import urllib.request
import boto3

def download(url):
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)


def upload_to_s3(channel, file):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    data = open(file, "rb")
    key = channel + '/' + file
    s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=key, Body=data)


# caltech-256 download('http://data.mxnet.io/data/caltech-256/caltech-256-60-train.rec')

upload_to_s3('train', 'caltech-256-60-train.rec')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is exactly as the error say, the variable `bucket` is not defined. 
you might want to do something like

```
bucket = <name of already created bucket in s3>
```

before you call

```
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=key, Body=data)
```

Comment: What exactly is key? on the doc it says `Object key for which the PUT action was initiated.` but not sure what that means, is it full s3 path u want to upload data to(Body)?