# Pandas Dataframe upload to Sagemaker to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have tried to find the solution for taking my dataframe and uploading it as a csv to S3. I tried this resource but I may be confused. [upload data to S3 with sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977679/upload-data-to-s3-with-sagemaker)

```
import boto3
s3 =boto.resource('s3')
bucket = 'work'
key = 'test.csv'
doc = df.to_csv('test.csv')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key= key, Body = doc)
```

I get the following error:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid 
types: <type 'str'>, <type 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

I am very new to s3 and using Sagemaker. I feel like what I am doing is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

give .upload_file(local_file) a try.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.Session().resource('s3')
bucket = 'your-bucket'
key = 'path-in-bucket/test.csv' # filepath in s3
doc = df.to_csv('test.csv') # your local file

s3.Bucket(bucket).Object(key).upload_file(doc)
```